# How to expose data from object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to pull the variables of connectData for some debugging. When I do type of I get object back thinking this was an array and I can do connectData[1] I get undefined,

So if I want to log out just the host name from connectData can someone please show me an example?

```
var connectData = {
    hostname: 127.0.0.1,
    port: 1521,
    database: "db", // System ID (SID)
    user: "usename",
    password: "password"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for-each loop to iterate through an object's properties.

```
var connectData = {
    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '1521',
    database: "db", // System ID (SID)
    user: "usename",
    password: "password"
};

for (var key in connectData) {
    if (connectData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        alert(key + " => " + connectData[key]);
    }
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mp6jS/1/

Comment: Here are the results, is there a way to get the value of the keys?hostname=>undefined
port=>undefined
database=>undefined
user=>undefined
password=>undefined

Comment: I think `connectData.key` should be `connectData[key]`.

Comment: @justZito Sorry about that. I corrected the code and included a working example.

Comment: ktm5124, the last thing you need to do is apologize that worked great.

Answer (score 2):

This is a javascript object, not an array.

You can access the individual elements by name. So to log just the hostname, you can do:

```
console.log(connectData.hostname);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about format being the issue. Is there some other aspect you are having trouble with? In your example above, the text 127.0.0.1 is not a valid javascript value - it should be wrapped in quotes as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Log it to the console. `console.log(connectData)`

In Chrome, you can view the console by right clicking, selecting "Inspect element", and clicking on the "Console" tab.